# calculating rows in text files (bash/perl)

Tags: perl, bash, join, merge

Which command/s do i need here? i guess `cat`  or `join -1 2 -2 2` , but for the calculation?  (else, should i code it myself using Regex? Is there any full featured commandline spreadsheet software?)

input.txt  (a list after "uniq -c")

> ```
>  1    abc
>  10   def
>  100  ghi
> ```

join.txt

> ```
> -1   def
> -1   def
> -10  ghi
> -10  ghi
> ```

Output:

> ```
> 1    abc
> 8    def
> 80   ghi
> ```

*..thanks=)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those files are tab-separated, save this and call it like:

```
perl sumfiles.pl src1.txt src2.txt
```

No error checking or what not in the script, and you could shorten it if you wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %scores;
while (my $l = <>) {
        chomp $l;
        my ($num, $key) = split(/\t/, $l);
        $scores{$key} += $num;
}

for my $k (sort keys %scores) {
        print "$scores{$k}\t$k\n";
}
```

EDIT: shorter version by @mpapec below. Well shorter except I'd end up adding 20 lines of comments so I could unwrap what it's doing... :-)

Comment: thanks!! (uniq -c lists have different white spaces but i will figure how to edit that accordingly)

Comment: Try `\s+` instead of `\t` then.

Comment: a leading one too.. so i just run 
perl -pi -e 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]*) (.*)/$1\t$2/' input  before...
more interessting tho:  how  does perl open both files in your script?

Comment: The `<>` is magic for "treat any command-line arguments as files and open and read from them one after the other". If there aren't any command-line args it'll try STDIN and other cleverness. See "I/O operators" here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html (or `perldoc perlop` on the command-line).

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MFile::Slurp -lane'
  BEGIN{ $s{ $_->[1] } += $_->[0] for map [split], read_file(pop) }
  $F[0] += $s{ $F[1] };
  print "@F";
' input.txt join.txt
```

output

```
1 abc
8 def
80 ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]+=$1;next}{print a[$2]+$1,$2}' join.txt input.txt

1 abc
8 def
80 ghi
```